# java how to convert string to String[] and put in Specific string variabel

Tags: java, string, list, oracle11g

i have a string with many value, i want to get all that`s value and put it to new String variable . after it done i would put it to String[]

in import lib :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;

import oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement;
import oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor;
import oracle.sql.ARRAY;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes;
import java.sql.*;
```

this my code :

```
private List<monitoringPpobModel> lisPpob= new ArrayList<monitoringPpobModel>();


con = dbEngine.getConnection();
OracleCallableStatement css = null;
for(int i=0;i<lisPpob.size(); i++)
        {   
           System.out.println("param 1 = "+lisPpob.get(i).getLBRAP2T());
           System.out.println("param 2 = "+lisPpob.get(i).getRPAP2T());

           ArrayDescriptor oracleVarchar2Collection = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("OPHARTDE.ARAY",con);

           List<String> lis= Arrays.asList(lisPpob.get(i).getLBRAP2T());
           List<String> lis2= Arrays.asList(lisPpob.get(i).getRPAP2T());

           String ket1 = lis.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
           String ket2 = lis2.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(","));

           //manual declare - this work
           String aa = "1";
           String bb = "3";
           String cc = "5";
           String dd = "7";
           String ee = "8";

           String[] lbr = {aa,bb,cc,dd,ee};
//         String[] lbr = {ket1};

           //auto declare - this not work 
           String[] rp = {ket2};

           ARRAY ora_lbr = new ARRAY (oracleVarchar2Collection, con,lbr);
           ARRAY ora_rp = new ARRAY (oracleVarchar2Collection, con,rp);

           System.out.println("value 1= "+ lbr.length +" = "+ lbr[i]);
           System.out.println("value 2= "+ rp.length +" = "+ rp[i]);

           css = (OracleCallableStatement) con.prepareCall("{call OPHARTDE.PPOBUPDATE2(?,?)}");
           css.setArray(1, ora_lbr);
           css.setArray(2, ora_rp);
           css.execute();
}
```

the result from println is :

```
param 1 = 75764674653, 5434, 354, 434, 5435
param 2 = 53, 535, 25, 53, 434
value 1= 5 = 1
value 2= 1 = 53, 535, 25, 53, 434
```

what i want is the value of :

```
String[] rp = {ket2};
```

is like value in

```
String[] lbr = {aa,bb,cc,dd,ee};
```

Thanks for help. it was so difficult for me. any help please

Comment: any help please. thanks

Comment: I have no idea what your questions is. Be precise.

Comment: get every value of string and put into string []

Comment: What value ? What String ? Be precise or you won't get any help. If you want us to invest time in your problem, invest some of yours making it easier for us. Also, writing properly helps.

Comment: i want get all value from ' ket2 '  and put it into new string, after it done i would put thats string to  ' String[] rp '.

Comment: Do NOT put more information into comments. Update your question instead.

Comment: Besides: read a little bit about java code naming conventions. ARRAY is pretty horrible name for a class.

Comment: You need to provide more information. You are using stuff which is not from the standard Java libraries - e.g. `ARRAY` seems to be a class. Also, `ArrayDescriptor`, which I suspect is from Oracle's JDBC, but you did not mention in your tags that your question is about Oracle database. And you are using data whose type we don't know (what is `listPob`?). Please [edit] your question and improve it.

Comment: @ali if I understand correctly you will want to look into a `regex` function. That can `split()` a `String` into a separate array.

Comment: @  Ethan Moore, can you give some example how regex function work

Answer (score 0):

This will put each character in a String object into an array of Strings.

`String[] rp = new String[ket2.length()];
 for(int i = 0; i < rp.length(); i++) {
     rp[j] = "" + ket2.charAt(i);
 }`

Tell me if this helps!

Comment: sorry i just open this site. actualy it was solved by me in fine my solution after many trying. but i must try your code for respect.

Comment: i was trying your code but give me error. a error log is ' java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01722: invalid number '.

Comment: this my solved code. i add this in my lis ' List<String> lis2= Arrays.asList(lisPpob.get(i).getRPAP2T().split("\\s*,\\s*"));  ' when i want get all value of lis this what i did  ' String[] myentries2 = lis2.toArray(new String[lis2.size()]); '. thanks

Comment: I don't know why the error occurred.  The code worked for me.  Glad to hear you got it working.